# Android-Error when trying to run on mobile device

Tags: android, runtime-error

I get the following error when I try to run the app on mobile device.Only sometimes the error is shown.I am using many github libraries in my project.I think it is something related to that. It worked perfectly yesterday.Please help me with this,

Error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.json:json:20140107 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubFlorent37Materialviewpager113Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubGanfraMaterialSpinner111Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJdAlexanderLibrary110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubKsoichiroAndroidObservablescrollview152Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubLguipengAnimCheckBox100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubOzodrukhCircularReveal131Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJpardogoMaterialtabstripLibrary110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMiguelcatalanMaterialsearchview140Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComOgaclejapanSmarttablayoutLibrary160Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComWdullaerMaterialdatetimepicker220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoNlopezSmartlocationLibrary321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
res\drawable\bg7.png:0: error: Resource entry bg7 is already defined.
res\drawable\bg7.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Jobin Sabu\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 4.426 secs
Information:1 error
Information:4 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.jobinsabu.destination"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
            } else {
                dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
            }
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    // ...
    maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
    maven {url 'http://yanzm.github.io/MaterialTabHost/repository'}
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'se.walkercrou:google-places-api-java:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.0@aar'
    compile ('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.1.3@aar'){
        transitive = true
    }

    compile 'com.github.lguipeng:AnimCheckBox:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete one of the bg7.png it is conflicting and giving error if you see error closely you will find this

```
res\drawable\bg7.png:0: error: Resource entry bg7 is already defined.
res\drawable\bg7.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
```